# Python 2.7: SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '0xe6' in file, error will not go away

Tags: python, utf-8, syntax-error

I have a python file with this line of text in it:

> The best 汉字 interests of the Aboriginal child in family law proceedings. Australian Journal of Family Law  12  140149.

I'm trying to process that line, but it keeps throwing the error:

> SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xa3' in file

I have put this at the top of the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Same error happens.

Also tried the following while leaving the utf 8 header above:

```
u'The best 汉字 interests of the Aboriginal child in family law proceedings. Australian Journal of Family Law  12  140149.'
```

Still same error.

Also tried the following while leaving the utf 8 header above:

```
unicode(The best 汉字 interests of the Aboriginal child in family law proceedings. Australian Journal of Family Law  12  140149.)
```

Still same error.

Also tried the following while leaving the utf 8 header above:

```
gettext.ugettext((The best 汉字 interests of the Aboriginal child in family law proceedings. Australian Journal of Family Law  12  140149.)
```

Still same error.

What am I missing?

Here's all the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

import re

s = u'The best 汉字 interests of the Aboriginal child in family law 
proceedings. Australian Journal of Family Law  12  140149.'

def cleanup(s):
    control_chars = ''.join(map(unichr, range(0,9) + range(11,13) + range(14,32) + range(127,160)))
    cc_regex = re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(control_chars))
    return cc_regex.sub(' ', s)

print cleanup(s)
```

Traceback outpout:

```
C:\EBI\Work>cd c:\EBI\Work && cmd /C "set "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" && set "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" && C:/Python27/python.exe 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\EBI\Work\test2.py", line 7, in <module>
    s = unicode('The best µ▒ëσ¡ù interests of the Aboriginal child in family law proceedings. Australian Journal of Family Law  12  140☺149.')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Can you produce a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show the full traceback? The UTF-8 encoding of `汉字` does not contain the byte `A3`, so either your source code isn't actually encoded with UTF-8, or the SyntaxError is caused by something else.

Comment: Added code to question.

Comment: First thing: you should use Unicode literals for text: `u'The best...'` – as you tried.

Comment: Secondly: Please show the full traceback (the lines starting with "Traceback (most recent call last):" and ending with the UnicodeError).

Comment: Added Traceback. Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't quite match your original problem. In the title your error message complains about byte `0xa3`, but now it's `0xe6` (which makes more sense with "汉字"). Also, please show the traceback for the current code version (the one with `u'The best...'`).

Comment: Btw: the fact that "汉字" is displayed as "µ▒ëσ¡ù" means that your terminal isn't configured to use UTF-8. This is outside Python's control, you need to configure the command-line program or use a better one.

Comment: There is no traceback when using u'...' it just prints this out: 'The best ├ª┬▒ ├Ñ┬¡  interests..." However the same error happens in the output tab.

Comment: Yes, in that case you have to adjust the terminal encoding, as I said in my previous comment. When you say "output tab", I guess you refer to some IDE, where you might have to do the same (configure the output encoding).

Comment: Just to be clear: With the SyntaxError and the UnicodeDecodeError you showed, there was a problem in line 7 (the definition of the string literal). The "├ª┬▒ ├Ñ┬¡" output you get now is connected to the `print` statement, some lines further down. These are two separate problems: defining a string, and printing it.